# Get data from json using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I'm trying to get some data from `JSON` below using **Retrofit**:

```
[
  {
    "country": "China",
    "cases": 80650,
    "todayCases": 98,
    "deaths": 3070,
    "todayDeaths": 28,
    "recovered": 55402,
    "critical": 5737
  },
  {
    "country": "S. Korea",
    "cases": 6593,
    "todayCases": 309,
    "deaths": 43,
    "todayDeaths": 1,
    "recovered": 135,
    "critical": 52
  }
....
]
```

I've tried the below code without success :

**Interface** :

```
public interface CoronaInterface {
    @GET("all")
    public Call<Resume> getCoronaVirusResumeInformation();

    @GET("countries")
    public Call<Complete> getCoronaVirusCompleteInformation();
}
```

**Models**

```
public class Data {
    @SerializedName("country")
    private String country;
    @SerializedName("recovered")
    private String recovered;
    @SerializedName("cases")
    private String cases;
    @SerializedName("critical")
    private String critical;
    @SerializedName("deaths")
    private String deaths;
    @SerializedName("todayCases")
    private String todayCases;
    @SerializedName("todayDeaths")
    private String todayDeaths;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public String getRecovered() {
        return recovered;
    }

    public String getCases() {
        return cases;
    }

    public String getCritical() {
        return critical;
    }

    public String getDeaths() {
        return deaths;
    }

    public String getTodayCases() {
        return todayCases;
    }

    public String getTodayDeaths() {
        return todayDeaths;
    }

}


public class Complete {
    private Data[] mData;

    public Data[] getData() {
        return mData;
    }

    public void setData(Data[] mData) {
        this.mData = mData;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity :**

```
mCallComplete = mCoronaInterface.getCoronaVirusCompleteInformation();
    mCallComplete.enqueue(new Callback<Complete>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Complete> call, @NonNull Response<Complete> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Complete> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ops", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**My issue:** I always get **ops** message at runtime.

Comment: why toast "ops"? toast error message. it will show the error why api call fails.

Comment: Describe more about the message you receive.

Answer (score 0):

Show Retrofit object.  Did you test your api using for example Postman program? is it working?

Answer (score 0):

Replace "ops" with t.toString() to see the details of what caused the error. As mentioned, you need to provide source of the API.